# file_get_contents(): file created in the system's temporary directory error in Magento

Tags: magento, laminas

I'm using magento 2.4.2-p1 and getting this error continously in my app as exceptions.

Report ID: webapi-6605b783362ae; Message: Notice: fil
e_get_contents(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /bitnami/magento/ven
dor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php on line 96

Why these errors are happening, anyone have idea?